# Store multiple rasters in an enterprise database, independently

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a large number of rasters with discontinuous data representing management plans for urban green areas which I want to store in an enterprise database independently. I don't want to mosaic the plans as it should be possible to turn on the plans individually.

When just loading the rasters to the database I get the preferred result but I want to put them in a dataset. Raster mosaic and Raster dataset seems to merge the rasters, and I have understood that Raster catalog is an old format.

The data should be stored in the enterprise database wherefore I don't want to use file geodatabases. Is this possible?

Comment: Enterprise geodatabase has not been a focus of Esri raster development for some time (since ArcGIS 9.2, in fact). Databases have proven to be slower, larger, harder to manipulate, and generally inferior to GeoTIFF. Esri is phasing out native raster support. This is not the best time to leap into enterprise raster use. Instead, I'd recommend you contact your local Esri office, and ask them to show you what you can accomplish with mosaic datasets, with and without the Image Server Extension.

Comment: Unfortunately It has to be an enterprise database because of security reasons.

Comment: Frankly, "security reasons" makes little sense in this context, but file-based data sources are quite compatible with PKI-secured web services.